# Parsing a CharSequence to double without creating String

Tags: java

I need to parse several gigabytes of text data with several hundred millions of lines in Java.

Each line is stored in a [`CharBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) (which implements [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)) and contains multiple integers and floating point numbers at fixed positions.

In a first version I used [`String.substring​(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) with [`Integer.parseInt​(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) and [`Double.parseDouble​(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-). This was however very slow. The garbage collector was eating up a lot of resources because of the creation of dozens of temporary String objects multiple times per line.

After I switched to [`Integer.parseInt​(CharSequence s, int beginIndex, int endIndex, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.CharSequence-int-int-int-) I got a major performance increase. It can parse the number directly from the [`CharBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html).

Unfortunately I cannot find such method for floating point numbers.

Does anyone know a method or library which provides floating parsing on [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and offsets instead of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Comment: I assume you are doing `CharBuffer.wrap(line)`? I don't understand where you would be using `String#substring`... if you know the fixed positions you could do `cb.position(position).limit(limit);` via a `for loop`, but that will still create lots of Strings

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not sure if it covers all of your expectations, it seems that [this library](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~jwo/giCentre/geomap/reference/org/gicentre/geomap/io/NumberParser.html) could provide something that you are looking for.

It provides the following method:

```
double parseDouble(java.lang.CharSequence s, int start, int end) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

*If it's not what you are looking for, sorry for taking your time.*

Answer (score 0):

The method below takes in `CharSequence` as a parameter and returns `double` without allocating any objects.

```java
public class NumberParser {

    public static double parseDouble(CharSequence chars) {
        long left = 0;
        long right = 0;
        long numRight = 0;
        int negateFactor = 1;
        boolean isDecimal = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
            char ch = chars.charAt(i);

            if (ch == '-') {
                negateFactor = -1;
                continue;
            }

            if (ch == '.') {
                isDecimal = true;
                continue;
            }

            int digit = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
            if (!isDecimal) {
                if (left == 0) {
                    left = digit;
                } else {
                    left *= 10;
                    left += digit;
                }
            } else {
                numRight++;
                if (numRight >= 9) break;
                if (right == 0) {
                    right = digit;
                } else {
                    right *= 10;
                    right += digit;
                }
            }
        }

        double decimal = left + right * Math.pow(10, -numRight);
        decimal *= negateFactor;
        return decimal;
    }
}
```